# moving many controls together to represent a Seating Chart in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

**Greetings,**
I want To create a graphic representation of a seating chart (could be in a wedding venue or in cars...). I used a splitted panel, in the splittedPanel1 i put the buttons to create the cars, and inside the splitted panel2 i want to put the graphic representation. Inside SplittedPanel2, I've created a panel and a pictureBox (to represent some fixed areas in the real world).
I've also created a class called SimpleCar. **SimpleCar is composed of 5 TextBox (es)  and a PictureBox all in a panel** to represent a car: the textBoses represent the passengers names and the car label, and the pictureBox to put an image representing a car (or a table). I've also made a sub to Add dynamically a SimpleCar. 
2 problems occur when i want to move this new panel (dynamically created), using MouseDown and MouseUp events:
- first pb: while moving the existing panel, **the screen flashes** and the **movement is not smooth**
- second pb: **i can't move a panel dynamically created**

*Note that moving a PictureBox by this code is very smooth but moving a panel is not user friendly.*

I expect **moving a dynamically created a panel smoothly**, *or should I reconsider displaying the cars in another way than in a panel*?
Knowing that the final purpose of the code is to export a picture of all the created tables in the venue. **I also tested the code with a groupBox** and the results aren't good.

***The simpleCar class is described in the code below:***

```
Class SimpleCar
    Public carNameBox, passengerNameBox1, passengerNameBox2,
            passengerNameBox3, passengerNameBox4 As TextBox
    Public carPictureBox As PictureBox
    Public carGroup As Panel
    Public Sub New()

        carGroup = New Panel

        carNameBox = New TextBox With {.Text = "carNmBx",
                                              .BackColor = Color.Yellow,
                                             .Name = "carNmBx"}
        passengerNameBox1 = New TextBox With {.Text = "txtPassNmBx1",
                                              .BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond,
                                             .Name = "TextBox1"}
        passengerNameBox2 = New TextBox With {.Text = "txtPassNmBx2",
                                               .BackColor = Color.AliceBlue,
                                             .Name = "TextBox2"}
        passengerNameBox3 = New TextBox With {.Text = "txtPassNmBx3",
                                             .BackColor = Color.Azure,
                                             .Name = "TextBox3"}
        passengerNameBox4 = New TextBox With {.Text = "txtPassNmBx4",
                                              .BackColor = Color.Cyan,
                                             .Name = "TextBox4"}
        carPictureBox = New PictureBox With {.Text = "picBx1",
                                             .BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond,
                                             .Name = "picBox1"}

        Dim fdialog As New OpenFileDialog()
        fdialog.FileName = String.Empty
        fdialog.Multiselect = True

        If fdialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            If fdialog.FileNames.Length = 2 Then
                carPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(fdialog.FileNames(0))

            ElseIf fdialog.FileNames.Length = 1 Then
                carPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(fdialog.FileName)

            End If
        End If
        carGroup.Controls.Add(carPictureBox)
        carGroup.Controls.Add(carNameBox)
        carGroup.Controls.Add(passengerNameBox1)
        carGroup.Controls.Add(passengerNameBox2)
        carGroup.Controls.Add(passengerNameBox3)
        carGroup.Controls.Add(passengerNameBox4)

    End Sub

End Class
```

***To Add dynamically a SimpleCar in the code below:***

```
 Public Sub Add_car()
    Dim carType As SimpleCar
    carType = New SimpleCar
    Dim carPs1 = carType.passengerNameBox1
    Dim carPs2 = carType.passengerNameBox2
    Dim carPs3 = carType.passengerNameBox3
    Dim carPs4 = carType.passengerNameBox4
    Dim carNm = carType.carNameBox
    Dim carPic = carType.carPictureBox
    Dim carGroupBox = carType.carGroup
    SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(carGroupBox)
  End Sub
```

***So the problem occurs when i use this code to move a panel (if you replace PictureBox by Panel, even GroupBox) (it worked fine when I wanted to move one control: PictureBox1 in this sample):***

```
'Drag To move PictureBox1 along with mouse-------------------------------------------
Dim oldX As Short
Dim oldY As Short

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    Dim X As Single = e.X
    Dim Y As Single = e.Y
    PictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll
    oldX = CShort(X)
    oldY = CShort(Y)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    Dim X As Single = e.X
    Dim Y As Single = e.Y
    PictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
' to limit the movement within the app----------------------------------
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim ProposedLocation As New Point(PictureBox1.Left - (oldX - e.X), PictureBox1.Top - (oldY - e.Y))
        PictureBox1.Left = CInt(IIf(ProposedLocation.X < 0, 0, IIf(ProposedLocation.X > SplitContainer1.Panel2.Width - PictureBox1.Width, SplitContainer1.Panel2.Width - PictureBox1.Width, ProposedLocation.X)))
        PictureBox1.Top = CInt(IIf(ProposedLocation.Y < 0, 0, IIf(ProposedLocation.Y > SplitContainer1.Panel2.Height - PictureBox1.Height, SplitContainer1.Panel2.Height - PictureBox1.Height, ProposedLocation.Y)))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could create a UserControl of all those controls so you are only creating and dealing with one control

Comment: In your opinion, is it the best way to approach the solution? I forgot to mention in the question that i may add more than 100 cars. Can you provide me a link or a sample to know how to implement a UserControl? i'm new to VB.Net and i can't figure out where to begin :-)
thanks for taking time to comment my question.